# Wordpress on single.php find category name

Tags: wordpress

I have a news wordpress site.

I have a nav that shows all the categories.

The post can have multiple categories so post can be in more than one category.

When I click the nav it opens a category.php page that shows all the posts in that category.

When you click a post in the category.php it opens the post in a single.php page.

How can I get the category on the single.php where the post came from.

Example:

Post-1 can be in category Red and Blue.

If in the nav I click Red, Post-1 will be in the category.php page.

If I click Post-1 on the category.php and it opens in the single.php I want to get the category where it came from  - Red

Is there a simple way to pace along the category from the category.php to single.php

Answer (score 0):

You can track it with the url from where you are coming mean to say that change your permalink according to category base.

Comment: Just trying that now - l'll post if I get it.